# Contained records only 1 level deep for afterFind?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a Schedule which hasMany Events.  Each Event belongsTo a Room.

I set up my options for a Contain'd find::

```
    $options = array(
            'conditions' => array('Schedule.' . $this->Schedule->primaryKey => $id),
            'contain' => array(
                'Event' => array(
                    'Room'
            // Etc.
```

I find everything using:

```
$sched = $this->Schedule->find('first', $options);
```

I have an afterFind method defined on the Event's model;  In that I copy the Room's name into the event's displayname so that the event can clearly identify which room it's in.

**The Problem:** In the afterFind method Event has no subsidiary records.  Specifically, it has no Room record.  If I do a normal/non-Contain'd find (with the $this->Schedule->recursive field set to 3) then I DO see the Room's data.

Is there a way for Contain to fetch data of a related record before the afterFind method is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, I'm guessing the reason you want to copy the room name into the event's display name is for a view?

May I suggest an alternative approach to this problem?

I think it would be far simpler to create a view helper to assist on rendering the event with its associated room information. It doesn't have to be too complex, for example:

*In your view:*

```
echo $this->Event->displayName($eventRecord)
```

Given the depth of documentation relating to the `containable` behavior, it is pure black-magic how it works and I personally wouldn't want to modify any of its code to do what you propose. I totally appreciate what you're trying to achieve but sticking to the principles of KISS, this seems like the right advice to give.

Answer (score 0):

In many situations, the Containable behavior will 'split' the `find()` query into separate queries and merge the results later on using PHP.

To force performing a *single* query, you may try to use `joins` in stead. However, because of the `hasMany`, using only joins will probably not be the most efficient query.

Joins-example;

```
$options = array(
        'conditions' => array('Schedule.' . $this->Schedule->primaryKey => $id),
        'contain' => array(
            'Event' => array(
                'joins' =>  array(
                    array(
                        'table' => 'rooms',
                        'alias' => 'Room',
                        'type' => 'INNER',
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'Room.id = Event.room_id',
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

**note**
I am *not* sure if CakePHP accepts joins to be defined **inside** a Contain. More information on manually specifying joins can be found here: [Joining Tables](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables)